# How should I install ng2-tag-input library to the angular-cli project?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, systemjs, angular-cli

I want to know how to use the ng2-tag-input library in my Angular 2 project.
My Angular 2 project was started with angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.24.
The project is used Angular 2.3.1 so that I set ng2-tag-input version as 0.4.8 and in the angular-cli.json file, I inserted this line.

```
"scripts": [
"../node_modules/ng2-tag-input/dist/ng2-tag-input.bundle.js"
]
```

And in the app.module.ts, I inserted "TagInputModule" to the imports array. But the `<tag-input>` didn't work and I got the error.

Answer (score 0):

1) Install the library `npm install ng2-tag-input --save`

2) Import **TagInputModule** to your module

```
import { TagInputModule } from 'ng2-tag-input';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ TagInputModule ]
})
export class YourModule {}
```

3) You don't need to add other configurations unless you are using SystemJS (Angular-cli is now using Webpack).

Comment: Yes, I am sure I imported the module.
Do you have some experience with [this angular2 starter project][1]?
I am using this starter project.I think in angular2 project, we need to map the 3rd party libraries. So for that, I tried to configure the angular-cli.json file as above, but it didn't work.
Do you have any idea?


  [1]: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli